# uint64 to hex array in Python

Tags: python, hex, byte, can-bus, socketcan

I have different uint64 numbers which I want to send via CAN-Bus with SocketCAN in Python. I need to divide the large number in 8 bytes, so I can assign the values to the CAN data-bytes. But I'm struggling with the implementation. 
I am grateful for any help or suggestion.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to convert numbers to their byte representation, the `struct` module is your friend:

```
i = 65357
print(hex(i))
bigendian = struct.pack(">Q", i)
littleendian = struct.pack("<Q", i)

print(repr(bigendian)
print(repr(littleendian)
```

output is as expected:

```
'0x10001'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01'
b'\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

That means that you can easily use the individual bytes (in the order you need) to send them via CAN-bus

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Python 3 you can simply use Python int's `to_bytes` method like so:

```
i = 65357
print(hex(i))
print(i.to_bytes(8, 'big'))
print(i.to_bytes(8, 'little'))
```

Output:

```
0xff4d
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xffM'
b'M\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Not sure if you're using the `python-can` library, but if you are you can pass either bytes, a list of ints or a bytesarray to the [can.Message](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.0/message.html#can.Message.data).